# Uploading an Image using formData to the server that is saved on drawable folder android in react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, cross-platform, form-data

I am trying to upload an image saved in the drawable folder in Android.
But I always get this error [TypeError: Network request failed]
Just so you know, this code is working fine on IOS and when the user selects an image from the device gallery or takes a photo from the camera.
Below is a snippet of the code.

```
formData.append("reward_image", {
                uri: 'file://bearicon',
                type: 'image/png',
                name: `image${cloutReward}.png`
            });
```

..